# Can capistrano or fabric be used to setup a server from scratch?

Tags: automation, capistrano, fabric

I'm hoping there is a light weight, command line utility that I could use to setup a server from scratch.

I like python's fabric or ruby's capistrano but from what I was reading they are more used for deployment purposes and not setting up apache, mysql, update patches etc.

I know there are other tools like puppet, but I don't want to setup a master/slave for servers etc., I was hoping there was a more light-weight tool for this.

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to set up a server/client infrastructure to use puppet, nor do you need to have a running puppetmaster daemon. You can point puppetd directly at a set of manifest files for your server and it'll happily get things configured for you.

Comment: +1 for writing the answer I would have. Puppet excels at this.

Comment: so normally the manifest files are provided by a puppetmaster daemon?

Comment: Yes, in a server/client setup, the manifests would be provided by puppetmaster, running on the master server.

Answer (score 4):

You could also look into making a setup using kickstart and pxe boots to do the preliminary setup.

Comment: Add [cobbler](https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/) to the mix.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using fabric for provisioning instances from scratch (a stock ubuntu image) on EC2; it works great. There are a few basic functions for appending to and commenting lines in a file that make modifying config files workable.